# How to randomly pick instanced instances in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm making a procedural building with geometry nodes where the walls are instanced on a generated profile from a grid and those instanced walls are being instanced vertically along a mesh line. While the 1st instance on points node is able to randomly pick mesh from a collection that contains more than 1 wall mesh, I can't find a way to randomize the walls being picked in the 2nd instance on points node which dictates the height of the building. I would also like to avoid using the realize instances node. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: pls show us your nodes tree or upload blend file...thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, you would only have to pass a random value when instantiating the objects in the individual floors, so that the objects from your collection are selected in different order.

What I do in this example:

1. First I create a floor from single points of a subdivided quadrilateral curve.
2. I multiply this floor with `Instance on Points` along a mesh line in the height and realize the points with `Realize Instances` *(The `Realize Instances` node is used here only to achieve the points for instantiation, but not to transform the individual objects to be instantiated)*.
3. Then I create a selection/mask with which I can separate the lowest floor from the upper floors.
4. When instantiating the upper floors with the node `Instance on Points`, I select the objects from the collection using a random value.

   [image]

Here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: I've tested it and it works quite well.